# Api call in render method of reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have a code in which an API call is made inside the render method in a react app, is it correct?
The API call is made from a function placed inside a const function which is placed in another file

Comment: When is the request triggered? Is it via an event (such as click)?

Comment: post a minimal code snippet please

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the use case.

There is nothing wrong with doing so as long as you aren't calling it everytime it re-renders. I assume you are making the request upon triggering of certain events(such as `onClick`). If yes, it may be cleaner to encapsulate it within a method.

```
async doSomething = () => {
 // do the rest
 // make API request
  await getRequest();
}

return <>
    <button onClick={() => this.doSomething()}/>
  </>;
```

If the request is to be made only once and when the component is initialised, you should make that request within the `componentDidMount` lifecycle hook. According to the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) for componentDidMount,

> componentDidMount() is invoked immediately after a component is
>   mounted (inserted into the tree). Initialization that requires DOM
>   nodes should go here. If you need to load data from a remote endpoint,
>   this is a good place to instantiate the network request.

Otherwise, calling it on `render()` will result in the API request to be triggered everytime there is a re-render.

Answer (score 0):

`render` method is place for presenting various elements to user and these elements can be used to trigger an api-call for various purposes. For example - checking validity of text entered in input-element, sending form-data async-ly to server, etc.

And this is a nice practice to put the code into various modules or separate files for better management, etc. for ex. call is wrapped inside a function and placed in a different file. `Webpack` helps in filling all various modules in place.

So it is alright to put api calls in render and calling a function defined inside another file for the same.

Answer (score 0):

It is not correct.

1) If the api call is waiting for the call to complete(await or promise resolve), Then it is essentially blocking render.

2) React might call render function many times[it may or not lead to DOM update], which means you will be making redundant api calls as many times.

It is ok to do so, if it is in response to an event.

So No, just put the api call in componentDidMount or ComponentDidUpdate or if you are using hook, add a useEffect.

Good Luck!